# Animate TR to disappear on ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I am using bootbox to create the following modal:

```
$("a.delete").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('item_', '');
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var table = $(this).attr('rel');
    bootbox.dialog({
      message: "Are you sure you want to delete this entry?",
      title: "Delete Confirmation",
      buttons: {
        success: {
          label: "Yes",
          className: "btn-danger",
          callback: function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "",
                data: 'deleteItem=' + id + '&table=' + table,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    parent.animate({
                        'backgroundColor': '#E3E3E3'
                    }, 400);
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg == "success") {
                        $('#projects').DataTable().row(parent).remove().draw();
                        $("html, body").animate({
                            scrollTop: 0
                        }, 600);
                        count();
                    } else if (msg == 'last') {
                        $('#rld_div').load("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?> #rld_div");
                    } else {
                        bootbox.alert(msg);
                    }
                    count();
                }
            });
          }
        },
        danger: {
          label: "No",
          className: "btn-primary"
        },
      }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete" rel="projects" id="item_206678293">Delete Project</a>
```

It strips the id from the id of the `<a>` and and gets the name of the table from the `rel`. Everything seems to be working but the parent (namely the tr), will not animate and just disappears

When I log the var `parent` I get this `[tr.odd, prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: a#item_250558768.delete]` so it seems to be selecting the right object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't animate background color using `animate()`

Comment: @charlietfl this code was working when I was using jquery ui to create a modal, it was only since the switch to bootbox, and im not sure how that would effect it

Comment: ok.. can't do it with jQuery core but jQueryUi adds enhancemts to animate. Create a demo that reproduces the issue

Comment: jquery-ui.js is still being called in the header... so it should work, no? do you have perhaps a better way for me to do this? I am trying to veer away from jquery-ui as I don't like it too much and much prefer bootstrap stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you're after the closest parent `<tr>` (assuming your link is in a table row), just use parent**s**('tr') (note the 's').

As far as the animation goes, I'm not sure that `beforeSend` will let you modify the DOM - [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) makes it seem like it's purpose is to allow you to modify the XMLHttpRequest object before the request it made. It might make more sense to move your animation outside the ajax request, and make the request in the "complete" callback for the [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

If that seems workable, you can also somewhat simply your code by using the `$.post` helper instead of `$.ajax`:

```
parent.animate({ 'backgroundColor': '#E3E3E3' }, 
    400,
    function(){
        var data = { 
            deleteItem : id, 
            table: table 
        };

        $.post(url, data)
            .done(function (msg, jhr, status) {
                if (msg == "success") {
                    $('#projects').DataTable().row(parent).remove().draw();
                    $("html, body").animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 600);
                    count();
                } else if (msg == 'last') {
                    $('#rld_div').load("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?> #rld_div");
                } else {
                    bootbox.alert(msg);
                }
                count();
            });
    });
```